# Implementation of RSA on google app engine webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encryption, cryptography

This is an assignment.
I have to create a web application on the google app engine and apply the rsa algorithm for storing data on the app engine datastore. My application just stores small notes created by the user. I have finished the application and also applied RSA for encrypting the messages (got code from [Implementing RSA algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920803/implementing-rsa-algorithm)). For that I split the string and convert each character to an ascii and then store them in a repeated `ndb.IntegerProperty` but I don't understand how the private and public keys are supposed to be handled. I want to know where do I store the private key and once the notes have been encrypted and the user accesses them again how do I get the public and private key? Am I supposed to store they keys in the datastore as well?

The encryption is done at the server to encrypt the notes that the user saves. The notes are strings which are broken into characters and their ascii values are then encrypted. All of this is done at the server side once the user clicks "add note".

The decryption is done at the server side when the user logs in and his user id is used to fetch the notes he has stored which are decrypted to get the original ascii values and then form the original string.

Currently there is only one key pair which is generated in the code.
link to the application : http://cloudassignment-1102.appspot.com

Let me know if I need to add the source code as well.

Comment: I updated my answer. I find it hard to give you a 100% answer since this is really an example of a useless exercise, so the true answer to where you should store your keys is 'wherever you want to'. For sake of simplicity i recommend to use the datastore as described in my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you store the private key somewhere (very) safe. Since GAE is the platform of your choice you have a couple of options:

- Put the key somewhere in your project where it is readable by the source code, but not publicly available (In Java this is usually a resources folder or WEB-INF, not sure what the equivalent for python is)
- Use cloud storage and put your file there. It's a bit of overhead but if you ever want to change the key open-heart-surgery style...
- Since a key is basically just an array of bytes you could define them as a constant byte array in your source. This would obviously be the least flexible choice.

EDIT:

Let me just say that this is a stupid assignment. It makes no sense at all to use asymmetric encryption if you hide all the encryption on your server. Since your data is always decrypted before it is sent to the user this is basically the same as symmetric encryption or no encryption at all.

But in the spirit of doing stupid things and learning while at it:

I assume your code generates the key pairs for each user. Therefore it is not possible to store the keys as constants in your code (GAE filesystem is readonly). Rather you can use any kind of database you wish (be it cloud datastore or cloud sql).

Since you should have a user database entity somewhere you can put the public key in there with the rest of the user information. You can serve the public key from the database through a cloud endpoint should you require it. Since it's not a secret you don't have to protect this endpoint.

The secret key could go in the same storage (datastore / cloud sql?) but i'd separate it so you cannot query for it and hand it out by accident. An additional table / entity with a reference to a user should suffice.

Comment: ok so I store the private key in my code and what about the public key?
should i have another ndb.model to map the private key with a particular user?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, where the public key is. It can be public. But wait... Is there a key pair for each user? If that is the case then the whole encryption/decryption should take place on the client side and you'd have to handle storing of keys on the client side. That would make the user's data secure, even from yourself :-)

Comment: but where do i store it publicly? should I keep them in the code as well?
yeah I realize keeping a key pair for each user would be more safe but then how do I handle storing of keys on the client side? for the private key I guess I can just store them in the cloud sql

Comment: If you have just the one keypair you can store the pub key the same way you store the secret key (in code?). On the client side: The client can store stuff in the localStorage in the browser for example. But you would need to move all of your encryption stuff to the client side including key creation. I don't really understand the concept of your encryption. Can you please extend your question and explain why data is encrypted, why you need RSA and not, let's say AES, and how data is stored on which side of your application (client / server).

Comment: this is just an assignment for my course where we need to create an application and show an improved form of RSA applied. As of  now I have only RSA applied and was confused about the storage of keys. The data is stored in the google cloud sql datastore(server side).

Comment: I will look into the client side creation and try to incorporate that otherwise i guess i'll let the keys be stored in the source code for now

Comment: another doubt. If I store the keys locally and the person accesses the application from another machine then how will I get the public keys?

Comment: That is why i asked you to describe the application in a bit more detail. The question is: Who encrypts what and where and who decrypts what and where. If all encryption is done on either the server or the client there is no need for asymmetric encryption at all. So who's encrypting? Please extend your question and don't use comments.

Comment: i've extended the question. I do want to have a key pair for each unique user, that's why I wanted to know how to handle the keys.

Comment: thanks. I did have a feeling that what i'm doing is indeed stupid and there really was no point of doing the encryption in the first place.
what would have been a better alternative to providing encryption for the data that the user wants to store? encryption decryption on the client side with storing the private key in my cloud?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92985/discussion-between-konqi-and-user3542154).